# Please include question title in title of revision history pages

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, revisions-list, seo

When using Google to search Stack Overflow today, I noticed that the revision history pages all share the title "Revisions - Stack Overflow". This is not very friendly to the search engine user:

http://img641.imageshack.us/img641/5190/revisiontitles.png

I would suggest using the current title of the post in the page's `<title>` tag.

In addition, a few SEO questions arise:

- *Should* revision history be exposed to search engines?  It is not very useful to new visitors, but it might include terms that the user searched for that have been edited away.
- Should the revision history include a `rel="canonical"` link back to the actual question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt

```
    User-Agent: *
    Allow: /
    Disallow: /posts
    Disallow: /posts/
```

Weird.

PS: `rel=canonical` should be used only for [identical or vastly similar (layout differences only) content](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html). In this case it would be mis-using it and google will ignore it for sure, and maybe even penalize the search rankings.

---

**EDIT**: mystery solved. It's the `Allow: /`; from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard#Allow_directive):

> Some major crawlers support an Allow
>   directive which can counteract a
>   following Disallow directive. This is
>   useful when you disallow an entire
>   directory but still want some HTML
>   documents in that directory crawled
>   and indexed. While by standard
>   implementation the first matching
>   robots.txt pattern always wins,
>   **Google's implementation differs in
>   that it first evaluates all Allow
>   patterns and only then all Disallow
>   patterns**.

In other words `Allow: /` overrides all the disallows and gives google access to the entire website.

Comment: yep, we disallow it from Google but somehow they slip in anyway.

Comment: @Jeff: maybe do the reverse of what you did in the sitemap? ie, if it's google send a 404

Comment: @Jeff: read my edit

Comment: maybe you should make it a new feature request (or bug?). it seems like a pretty big deal, as it makes the site's current robots.txt useless

Comment: well this part (thanks Kop!) is [status-completed] anyway..